# upload data to server memory

Tags: php

I'm using PHP

I understand that its possible to upload value to the server memory

Lets says that every user have table of permissions for the website

I don't want to do query for permission every time user load some page. I s it possible to load all permission in advanced to the server memory and pull them every time he slide to a new page?

Thank you in advance,
Roi.

Comment: Where and how is your permissions stored? For example is one 32-bit mask enough or do you need something more advanced? _$_SESSION['index']_ works just like any other variable while reading/writing from/to it. Difference is in "variable scope": _$_SESSION_ is always usable after starting session and lasts as long as you maintain your session storage (_session files_).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the $_SESSION scope. Documented under http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: call for session is better than create query for every page?
and - do I need session for each permission?